# Android In App Purchase Remove Ads

Tags: android

I am trying to implement in app purchase remove ads following this [tutorial](http://www.tutorialsface.com/2016/05/implementing-remove-ads-in-app-purchases-in-android-tutorial-example/). However, I am stuck in `MyBillin.java`'s `import com.marothiatechs.ZBHelpers.Constants`. The author did not mention what it contains. I posted a comment 11 days ago but do not get a reply. Anyone has an idea on what it contains?

Comment: It appears to contain a value that determines if ads are disabled.

Answer (score 0):

The code only seems to access a boolean property called `isAdsDisabled`
You can add the class yourself:

```
package com.marothiatechs.ZBHelpers;

public abstract class Constants {
    public boolean isAdsDisabled;
}
```

Comment: Tried to add this class, but do not work. Is there any other way to make it work without the constants?

Comment: Sorry pal, but adding this class should fix the main issue of your topic. 
If a new problem arise, create a new question with the stacktrace or the compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

```
public abstract class Constants {
    public static boolean isAdsDisabled;
}
```

This will solve your problem.